# In Java byte take 8 bits and range is -128 to 127 why it is not -127 to 128?

Tags: java, c, types, byte

why range is not equally divided it can be -127 to 128. and if we consider range -128 to 127 then -128 can not be represented in 8 bits. -128 in binary 1100000000 first bit is for sign bit.

Comment: Learn about [two's complement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: You need to read up on how [Two's Complement notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) works.

Comment: -128 = binary 10000000. A 16-bit integer would go from -32768 to -32767.